# CSS / HTML - Transition doesn't trigger

Tags: html, css

I have an LI list, with anchor links in, which will get a border around them on hover. I want to use the transition style for whenever the links are hovered, to make the border-color ease in.

This is what I am doing:

```
    .sidemenu li a {
    transition: border-color 2s ease;
    -webkit-transition: border-color 2s ease;  

}

.sidemenu li a:hover {
    border:1px solid #27AE60;

}
```

Although this doesn't work - when hovering, it just appears instantly.

Please see **[this JSFIDDLE for reference](http://jsfiddle.net/v1zswam8/)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because you don't have an initial value to make the `"from-to"` transition, try this:

```css
.sidemenu li a {
  transition: border-color 2s ease;
  -webkit-transition: border-color 2s ease;
  border:1px solid transparent;
}
.sidemenu li a:hover {
  border: 1px solid #27AE60;
}
```

```html
<div class="sidemenu-container">
  <ul class="sidemenu">
    <li class="head">Account Overview</li>
    <li>
      <a href="#"><i class="ic ic-pulse"></i> My Account</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I've copied your exact code - still doesn't work. Though it works in the code snippet you've posted.

Comment: @oliverbj on fiddle works too http://jsfiddle.net/v1zswam8/1/ ... I just add the intial state for the `border` property.

Answer (score 1):

You need to define a transparent border to be able to see the transition, so :

```
.sidemenu li a {
    /* add this line */
    border:1px solid transparent;
    transition: border-color 2s ease;
    -webkit-transition: border-color 2s ease;  
}
```

updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/v1zswam8/3/

Answer (score 0):

You have to do it this way:

```
   .sidemenu li a {
        border: solid 1px #fff;
        -webkit-transition: border 2s;

    }

    .sidemenu li a:hover {
        -webkit-transition: border 2s;
        border:1px solid #27AE60;

    }
```